secure conditional render in Nuxt component
I am trying to implement a Nuxt3 component which is rendered only if a user has Administrator role. Otherwise it should render 'You are not authorized to view this content.'
I am fetching roles from my backend using useFetch during server render and dynamically import a component that renders secure content.
It works fine if I do not check if it runs at the server render time only (process.server), but if I do, then after hydration the component is null and not rendered.
But if I won't import the component at the SSR only, an attacker can easily tamper clients code to import secure content component.
Here is the component code:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useCookie, useFetch } from '#app';
import {Roles} from '@lionberg/genius-shared/dist/types/access/roles'

const check = ref(false);  // Initially set to false
const DynamicComponent:any = shallowRef(null);
const token = useCookie('genius_access_token');
const { data } = await useFetch('/api/getRoles', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token.value}` },
  server: true
});


check.value = false;

// I cannot check if ( process.server ) because it won't render.
if (data.value.roles.includes(Roles.Administrator)) {
    DynamicComponent.value = (defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./securedControl.vue')));
    check.value = true;  
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
      <!-- Render the secure component if authorized -->
      <component v-if="check" :is="DynamicComponent"><slot/></component>
      <!-- Show 'not authorized' message if not authorized -->
      <div v-else>You are not authorized to view this content.</div>
  </div>
</template>


How to securely import a component dynamically and render it conditionally?
Basically, I want to implement an analogy of C# Blazor <Authorized> component
